# Setting up hostmask for IRC users

Tags: networking, hosts, irc

I have set up an irc network but i would like to hide the ip address of users that connect to the network. I have BNC, is that something i can use to mask everyone's ip or just mine? I just want an automatic user mode +x

Comment: What IRCd are you using?

Comment: bahamut ircd asdfasdkfjelk

Comment: Wouldn't "I am using Bahamut ircd" have covered the length requirement just as well?... Anyway, are you using any services software like Anope or Atheme?